# Does every module over a commutative local ring direct sum of all its indecomposable submodules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, direct-sum

Let $R$ be a commutative local ring and $M$ be an $R$-module. To determine the structure of $M$, does it suffice to determine the structure of all indecomposable summands of $M$ and then say that $M$ is a direct sum of this submodules?
Thank you.

Comment: Indecomposable submodules can contain proper submodules, so $M$ will almost never be the *direct* sum of *all* of its indecomposable submodules. You can ask that it's the sum (not direct) of its indecomposable submodules, or that it's a direct sum of *some* indecomposable submodules.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I see in an article that the author, for determine the structure of a module $M$ say that, "Let $T$ denote an inecomposable summand of $M$." Then he determines the structure of $T$ and finally he say that "Thus $M$ is a direct sum of copies of modules of the form $T$." Is this method of proof true? can you help me? thanks. The name of article is, "ON SECONDARY MODULES OVER PULLBACK RINGS" the proof of Proposition 2.3. thanks a lot.

Comment: @SAliMousavi: I haven't looked at the article, but probably there are some additional things known about $M$ (e.g., that it is finitely generated) which allow you to conclude that it is a direct sum of indecomposable modules in that context.  In any case, that sentence certainly isn't asserting that $M$ is the direct sum of _all_ of its indecomposable submodules, just that it is possible to write it as a direct sum of indecomposable submodules in _some_ way.

Comment: As far as I remember, the property that any module is a direct sum of indecomposable modules is much stronger than being noetherian.